# How to edit trashed item

Tags: edit, laravel-backpack, soft-delete, edit-trashed-item-backpack

I want to edit a trashed item which is soft deleted, but it is giving 404 error.
The url is like /admin/orders/7/edit
Also the show page giving 404 /admin/orders/7/show

I tried implementing below:

1. Trash Operation.
2. custom middleware to ResolveTrashedModelForBackpack

Answer (score 0):

You can not edit a deleted item; to do this, you need to restore, by default, in a query is checked that is_deleted is null.

If you want to add this feature, you will need to override the query like this:

```
Model::withTrashed()->get();
```

Cheers.